# How to test Mass Assignment in Rails 4 using RSpec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Given a simple User model, in Rails 4 with name, email, and an admin boolean, what's the best approach to testing mass assignment using RSpec?

Here's the UsersController:

```
def create
  @user = User.new user_params
  ...snip
end

private

  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email)
  end
```

and two different tries at testing this:

in user_spec.rb

```
describe "accessible attributes" do
  describe "should not allow access to admin" do
    before do 
      @user.admin = "1"
      @user.save
    end
    it { should_not be_admin }
  end
end
```

or in users_controller_spec.rb

```
it 'should only allow name and email to be set' do
  @controller.user_params.keys.should eq(['name', 'email')
end
```

Neither work - the former just creates a user with admin set to true (failing the test) - presumably this bypasses strong_parameters. The latter works, but only if the user_params method is not private.  (The official docs recommend setting it to private.  Note - watching for a MassAssignment error in the user_spec doesn't work either (no error is raised).

Note - actually setting the user to admin in a view correctly works - the admin attribute is filtered out and all is happy, but would really like to see this working properly in a test.

An alternative suggest is to use the shoulda-matchers gem with the user_spec.rb:

```
describe User do
  ...
  it { should_not allow_mass_assignment_of(:admin) }
  ...
end
```

(this doesn't work either), giving:

```
Failure/Error: it { should_not allow_mass_assignment_of(:admin) }
 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `active_authorizer' for #<Class:0x007f93c9840648>
```

(I assume this error is due to the fact shoulda-matchers isn't Rails 4 compatible yet).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: have a look at https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers

Comment: Doesn't look like that's working at present, getting: NoMethodError:
       undefined method `active_authorizer'  (probably due to Rails 4 being in beta)

Comment: describe User do
  it { should_not allow_mass_assignment_of(:admin) }
end ------->
use it on top

Comment: That makes no difference to the error - I'll update the question for reference.

Comment: This is an answer I posted to a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26661956/2183673

Answer (score 1):

```
it "should not allow mass assignment" do
  raw_parameters = { :admin => 1 }
  parameters = ActionController::Parameters.new(raw_parameters)
  expect {@user.update_attributes(parameters)}.should raise_error
end
```

In order to test mass assignment you should simulate passing parameters from controller.

https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters#use-outside-of-controllers

Comment: That still fails with Failure/Error: it { should_not be_admin } expected admin? to return false, got true

Comment: do you have `attr_accessible` or `attr_protected` in your User model?

Comment: This is Rails 4, attr_accessible is no longer used, as it's replaced with strong parameters? (So, no, in answer to your question)

Comment: Sorry, doesn't work either - that passes both without or with :admin in the .permit method in the controller.

Comment: Weirdly, even if add :admin to the permit list, your code in the console raises: ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError: ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError

Comment: in my console `@user.update_attributes(params)` raises. But `@user.update_attributes(params).permit(:admin)` going ok.