# How to test strong params with Rspec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, rspec-rails

What is the actual strategy to test strong params filtering in Rails controller with Rspec? (Except shoulda matchers) How to write failing test and then make it green?

Comment: Did my answer help? Maybe I can clarify something.

Comment: Thank you, you really helped me. I didnt know about with_indifferent_access. And how to test attributes requirements, like params.require :user?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Create 2 hashes with expected and all (with unsatisfied) parameters. Then pass all params to action and check that you object model receiving only expected params. It will not if you are not using strong parameter filters. Than add permissions to params and check test again.

For example, this:

```
# action
def create
  User.create(params)
end

# spec
it 'creates a user' do
  expect_any_instance_of(User).to receive(:create).
    with({name: 'Sideshow Bob'}.with_indifferent_access)
  post :create, user: 
    { first_name: 'Sideshow', last_name: 'Bob', name: 'Sideshow Bob' }
end
```

will pass all params to User and test will fail. And when you filter them:

```
def user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:name)
end
```

and change action with `User.create(user_params)`, test will pass.

Comment: `create` is a class-level method defined on `ActiveRecord::Base` and inherited by `User`.

So while `expect_any_instance(User)` (mock expectation on an instance of `User`) _might_ work, `expect(User)` (mock expectation on the `User` class) will work as well and is more minimal.

Answer (score 11):

I personally use [shoulda-matcher](https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers/blob/v2.8.0/lib/shoulda/matchers/action_controller/strong_parameters_matcher.rb) from thoughtbot.

With something like:

```
it do
  should permit(:first_name, :last_name, :email, :password).
    for(:update, params: params)
end
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is how I did it:

```
  describe 'Safe Params' do

   let(:mixed_params) {
     {
       blueprint_application_environment: {
         id: 1000,
         blueprint_id:   1,
         application_id: 2,
         environment_id: 3
       },
       format: :json
     }
   }

context "when processing a Post request with a mix of permitted and unpermitted parameters" do
   before { post :create, mixed_params }

  it "a create will not set the value of the unpermitted parameter" do
     expect(JSON.parse(response.body)["id"]).not_to eq(1000)
   end

  it "a create will set the value of the permitted parameters" do
     expect(JSON.parse(response.body)["blueprint_id"]).to eq(1)
     expect(JSON.parse(response.body)["application_id"]).to eq(2)
     expect(JSON.parse(response.body)["environment_id"]).to eq(3)
   end
 end
```

end

Controller code:

```
  def create
    @blueprint_application_environment = BlueprintApplicationEnvironment.new(blueprint_application_environment_params)
    if @blueprint_application_environment.save
      render 'show.json.jbuilder'
    else
      render json: @blueprint_application_environment.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end

def blueprint_application_environment_params
    params.require(:blueprint_application_environment).permit(:blueprint_id, :application_id, :environment_id)
end
```

Answer (score 1):

as like you create or update object using strong parameters,it is also similar except one thing that normal you do like this:

> post :create, book_id: @book.id

But in strong parameter you have to do like this:

> post :create, {book_id: @book.id, **comment: {user_id: 101, book_id:
>   @book.id, description: "worth to buy"}**}

you have to pass in nested parameters.